# android set specific characters as inputType

Tags: android

I'm looking for a way to "customize" the `inputType` of a `EditText`. The user should enter a date which has the format `dd.mm.yyyy` (and yes, I don't want to use a date picker). Setting the `inputType` to `numberDecimal` allows entering only one point, but I would like to have only the numeric keyboard, not the whole one. Is there an easy way reaching that without writing a custom keyboard?

So basically I just want to use [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,.]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Whenever you limit the input to a unique set of characters you can use the [digits](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3adigits) attribute:

```
android:digits="01234567890./-"
```

Every characters you specify can be used one or more times, you can even include letters and other symbols.

Comment: I'll try that too! Will only the numeric keyboard be shown respectively only the defined characters? (sorry I'm not at the main PC anymore to try it by myself)

Comment: You can combine `android:digits="012abc"` with `android:inputType="number"` to set the numeric keyboard as the default but still allow letters.

Answer (score 4):

The solution is very simple: `inputType="date"`.

The problem first was, that in my AVD the chinese and japanese keyboard are activated. It seems that there is a bug when trying to enter a point. So I just removed these two languages as additional keyboard languages and it works.

Comment: Upvote for the simplest answer, but I added mine in case you want to specify a distinct character.